# asignar función a skip

Tags: angular

tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con angular y requiero que cuando le de click en "skip", pues como bien se sabe, se pasa a la siguiente sección, el problema que estoy teniendo es que le paso la función, pero todo el texto queda para clickear y poder pasar a la siguiente sección, es decir, puedo dar click en cualquier otra palabra y continua la ejecución del codigo

```js
const tcText = 'you may click on <a class="skip 2" (Click)="onSetEmail()">Skip</a> to download links directly.';
```

```html
<p (click)="onSetEmail()" [innerHTML]= "this.tcText" ></p>
```

En resumen, con este codigo que muestro, le puedo dar cllick a you y me llama la función, cuando solo deberia de funcionar cuando me pare sobre skip y clickee sobre el mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema por el cual se te activa el click en toda la frase es porque estás capturando al evento **click** para todo el párrafo

```
<p (click)="onSetEmail()" [innerHTML]= "this.tcText" ></p>
```

Deberías dejarlo así

```
<p [innerHTML]= "this.tcText" ></p>
```

Por otro lado, lo que estás intentando hacer no funcionaría porque dentro del texto capturas el evento (click), pero Angular sólo puede procesar este evento en tiempo de compilación, mientras que tú lo estás intentado procesar en tiempo real al renderizarlo.

Se podría intentar alguna aproximación Por ejemplo, si tu texto siempre sigue el patrón

```
[texto1][link][texto2]
```

podrías hacer algo como esto, cambia la variable pasada desde un string a un objeto, de la siguiente manera

```
tcText = {
    texto1: 'you may click on ',
    textoLink:'Skip',
    texto2: ' to download links directly.'
  };
```

y luego en tu plantilla puedes cambiar la salida por la siguiente

```
<p><span [innerHTML]= "tcText.texto1"></span><span [innerText]="tcText.textoLink" class="skip2" (click)="onSetEmail()"></span><span [innerHTML]= "tcText.texto2"></span></p>
```

Comment: Si, pero la pregunta sería, como se puede realizar esta función?, o si hay alguna manera diferente de realizarlo o definitivamente no?

Comment: Te he ampliado la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias Pedro, que tengas un excelente día :), saludos